# How to return result printed in php

Tags: php, symfony, google-ads-api

I want to return the result printed , to use in other function.

Here is the code:

```
"Keyword idea text '%s' has %d average monthly searches and competition as %d.%s",
$result->getText()->getValue(),
is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches()->getValue(),
is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getCompetition(),
PHP_EOL
);

return
```

The result is like : Keyword idea text 'a' has 1600 average monthly searches and competition as 4.
Keyword idea text 'b' has 10 average monthly searches and competition as 2.
Keyword idea text 'c' has 10 average monthly searches and competition as 4.

this is how is printed

i want to return like "a,b,c"

How to store this result in one string and to retunr ....so then i can use in other function

Comment: `return $result->getText()->getValue() . ',' . is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches()->getValue() . ',' . is_null($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) ?
0 : $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getCompetition();`

Comment: What's the exact problem with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method:

```
return $a . ',' . $b . ',' . $c;
```

Second Method

```
$arr = [$a, $b, $c];
return implode(",", $arr);
```